# Jasmine spyOn diffent between Chrome and IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I had the following test

```
  it('should send message to window...', inject(
    [AppEventsService],
    (service: AppEventsService) => {
      spyOn(window.parent, 'postMessage').and.callThrough();
      service.sendMessage('MyTestEvent', 'empty');
      expect(window.parent.postMessage).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        JSON.stringify({ e: 'MyTestEvent', v: 'empty' }),
        '*'
      );
    }
  ));
```

this works in Chrome but in IE I got

```
Error: <toHaveBeenCalledWith> : Expected a spy, but got Function.
Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...arguments)
```

but why? The method in service does the following

```
 public sendMessage(event: string, param: string) {
    const message = {};
    message['e'] = event;
    if (StringUtils.isNullOrWhiteSpace(param)) {
      message['v'] = '';
    } else {
      message['v'] = param;
    }

    window.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(message), '*');
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in IE 11, the `postMessage` method's propertyDescriptor is marked as non-writable and non-configurable. So, on IE 11, you cannot overwrite that property.

Your best approach here is to wrap the `windows.parent.postMessage` method in a custom method, like this:

```
function postToParent(...args) {
  return window.parent.postMessage(...args);
}
```

and then replace all calls to `window.parent.postMessage` with `postToParent`.

Finally, in your tests, do:

```
spyOn(window, 'postToParent').and.callThrough();
```